# How to increment the number from 00.000000 to 48.853373 in few seconds by 0.00001

Tags: javascript

I am using map coordinates as a part of website logo. (2.378628, 48.853373).

What I want to do, is count both numbers from 0.000000 so they reach given points during the same time (3-5 seconds), incrementing by 0.000001. How is that possible? This crashes my computer, and setInterval does sth every ms, which is not enough.

```
while (i < 48.853373) {
  i = i + 0.000001;
  $('.js-center-lat').text(i);
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate why are you doing this?

Comment: If it's part of an animation, you could try finding a solution through CSS or by using `window.requestAnimationFrame()` to take advantage of your GPU.

Comment: You are using it for the logo slowly change, right?

Comment: You're never going to get a browser (or anything else) to repaint that quickly; that'd be in million-frames-per-second range.

Comment: @BojanIvanac answer is correct. You'll have to write the animation to be asynchronous and preferably take advantage of requestAnimationFrame

Comment: Most likely you will want to emulate the numbers growing like that, not actually incrementing them.  Something like this: https://inorganik.github.io/countUp.js/

Comment: @SilvioBiasiol I want to use it as a kind of loader. My website is based on mapbox, and the part of the logo are those coordinates, which updates while browsing the map. I wanted to add this animation. It can be faked in last digits part, the most important is that user perceive it as a real counter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want to "animate" the floating point number to count up to a defined value. 
Have you considered third party libraries, like [CountUp.js](https://inorganik.github.io/countUp.js/)?

> CountUp.js is a dependency-free, lightweight JavaScript "class" that can be used to quickly create animations that display numerical data in a more interesting way.

Quick example on how to use it:

```js
var options = {
  useEasing: true, 
  useGrouping: true, 
  separator: '', 
  decimal: '.', 
};

var demo = new CountUp('myTargetElement', 0, 2.415543, 6, 2.5, options);

if (!demo.error) {
  demo.start();
} else {
  console.error(demo.error);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It works perfectly, even better, I wasn't planning to have an easing! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You take the time when you started the animation (`startTime`), and you have value how long the animation should last (`duration`).

For each animation step you can calculate the percentage of the animation.

And with that percentage you can count up multiple values.

```js
let startTime = Date.now();
let duration = 3000;

function updateText() {
  let percent = Math.min(1, (Date.now() - startTime) / duration);
  // Math min ensures that percent does not become larger then 1

  $('.val1').text(50 * percent); // 0 - 50
  $('.val2').text(33 * percent); // 0 - 33
  $('.val3').text(13 + 10 * percent); // 13 - 23

  if (percent <= 1) {
    requestAnimationFrame(updateText)
  }
}

updateText();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="val1">
</div>
<div class="val2">
</div>
<div class="val3">
</div>
```